# How iterate for s3 file keys via CompletableFuture in aws sdk 2.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, java-8, aws-sdk

Consider example about sync version and old aws sdk:

```
public void syncIterateObjects() {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = null;
    String marker = null;
    do {
        ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(
                new ListObjectsRequest()
                        .withBucketName("bucket")
                        .withPrefix("prefix")
                        .withMarker(marker)
                        .withDelimiter("/")
                        .withMaxKeys(100)
        );
        marker = objects.getNextMarker();
    } while (marker != null);
}
```

Everything is clear - do/while do the work. Consider async example and awsd sdk 2.0

```
public void asyncIterateObjects() {
    S3AsyncClient client = S3AsyncClient.builder().build()

    final CompletableFuture<ListObjectsV2Response> response = client.listObjectsV2(ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
            .delimiter("/")
            .prefix("bucket")
            .bucket("prefix")
            .build())
            .thenApply(Function.identity());

    // what to do next ???
}
```

Ok I got CompletableFuture, but how run cycle to pass marker (`nextContinuationToken` in aws sdk 2.0) between previous and next `Future`?

Answer (score 0):

You have only one future, notice the type is a future list of objects. 
now you have to decide if you want to `get` the future or apply further transformations to it before getting it. After you get the future you can use the same method you used before with the `while`